# How to fix 403 Forbidden error after deploying Laravel app to Azure App Service?

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple Laravel app in Azure DevOps. Below is my `yml` file for the CI logic and I can successfully create a release and deploy it to an Azure App Service. However, when I load the `url` I get a `403 Forbidden` error. If more info is needed please let me know!

```yaml
    trigger:
    - main
    
    variables:
      # Agent VM image name
      vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
      # Root folder under which your composer.json file is available.
      rootFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: Build stage
      variables:
        phpVersion: '8.2'
      jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
        - script: |
            sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
            sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
            sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
            sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
            sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
            php -version
          workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
          displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'
    
        - script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
          workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
          displayName: 'Composer install'
    
        - script: |
            cp .env.example .env
            php artisan key:generate
            php artisan config:clear
            php artisan config:cache
          workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
          displayName: 'Set Laravel Environment'
      
    
        - script: php artisan test
          displayName: 'Run tests with phpunit'
    
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          displayName: 'Archive files'
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(rootFolder)'
            includeRootFolder: false
            archiveType: zip
            archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            replaceExistingArchive: true
    
        - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
          displayName: 'Upload package'
          artifact: drop
```

Comment: Have you enabled any firewall restriction from your Web App side? You haven't shared the pipeline task(s) for Web App deployment or the [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops). To isolate the issue to be caused by Azure DevOps or web app, can you please try to deploy the `$(Build.BuildId).zip` from your local machine by the command like `az webapp deploy` and may I know if it could reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-php?tabs=cli&pivots=platform-linux) to clone a sample PHP Web app in my ***Azure Repository*** and ran an **Azure DevOps yaml pipeline** to deploy it like below:-

***Click on Azure Pipeline> Select your Azure Repository with the Web app source code > Select PHP as Linux Web App on Azure YAML Template > It will ask you select and log in to your subscription that contains your Azure Web App with PHP Runtime > Select your Web App > Validate and configure:-***

[image]

Azure DevOps yaml pipeline created by above template:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxx-1691f3fdf982'

  
  webAppName: 'siliconphpLA'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  environmentName: 'siliconphpLA'

  
  rootFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  variables:
    phpVersion: '7.3'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - script: |
        sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
        sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
        php -version
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'

    - script: composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
      workingDirectory: $(rootFolder)
      displayName: 'Composer install'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(rootFolder)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : siliconphpLA'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***My Web App Loads successfully :-***

[image]

If your Web app is connected to database and behind a Private VNET, Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/tutorial-php-database-app) for the configuration and run the same pipeline for deployment.

Refer my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77571242/azure-web-app-miss-nginx-after-deployment/77578022#) to load your app with start up command.

Comment: Just realized this approach is not using the release pipeline!