# How to deploy Laravel-Inertia (Vue-3, PHP-8.0) project in Azure web app instance?

Tags: laravel, azure, vuejs3, azure-web-app-service

I have created a project using laravel inertia concept, but in the time of deploy there is a gap to deploy Vue section in Azure Web app instance, I have facing, can please guide me on these? how to deploy this kind of project step by step..

No feature found to automate vue section, like $ npm run watch or $ npm run prod.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy your `PHP +VUE` app you can directly deploy it via ***1) VS code Azure Web app extension OR 2) By pushing your project code to Github and then using Github Action Workflow*.**

**Github Action workflow:-**

In your **`Azure Web App visit Deployment center> Select Source as Github > sign into your Github repository > Select your Github Organization > Repository with PHP code > Branch > Select Save`**:-

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

By default PHP 8.0 and above loads the Web app from nginix server from the php public folder but the Azure Web app deploys the Php project to home/site/wwwroot Thus you need to add a custom startup script to load the public folder from home/site/wwwroot/default to nginix.

Refer these [MS Q & A answers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/542749/deploying-an-app-service-with-laravel-8-and-php-8) and this [Blog](https://www.schakko.de/2021/09/08/deploying-php-8-0-applications-with-azure-app-service/) for detailed steps to deploy PHP laravel app to Azure Web app.

According to the  above MS Q & A Answer and this [Ms community blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/configure-nginx-for-php-8-linux-azure-app-service/ba-p/3069373) copy the nginx default file to home/site/default folder and then edit it like below by ssh'ing into your Azure Web App:-

**Commands:-**

```bash
apt update
apt install rsync
cd /home/site
nano default
```

**`default file:-`**

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
```

**Startup command:-**

```
cp /home/site/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
service nginx reload
```

Additional Reference for PHP deployment with Azure DevOps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77590403/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-after-deploying-laravel-app-to-azure-app-service/77599438#77599438).